# How do I prevent a batch file from outputting any error?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, output, echo

The following command outputs some error (e.g. "**The specified path was not found**" ...).
How can I prevent this command from displaying anything ?

```
@echo off

cd C:\test
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    echo [test]>"%%a\test.txt"
    echo %%a >>"%%a\test.txt"
)
```

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

cd C:\test 2>nul || exit /b 1
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    echo [test]>"%%a\test.txt"
    >>"%%a\test.txt" echo %%a
)
```

If `C:\test` does not exist, then `cd` will message the error to stderr of *path not found*. You can silence the error message by redirecting stderr to nul with `2>nul`. `2` is the stderr stream.

Since `cd` is important for the following code in the script, then use of `||` which is if previous command fails, do the command following that command with `exit /b 1`.

Also, to avoid trailing space with echo to file, you can place the redirect before the echo command instead of after e.g. `>>"%%a\test.txt" echo %%a`.

Or e.g. from comment:

```
@echo off
set "Source=C:\test"
set "Target=D:\data"

cd "%Source%" 2>nul || exit /b 1
if not exist "%Target%" exit /b 2

for /d %%a in (*) do (
    >  "%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo [test]
    >> "%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo %%a
)

pause
exit
```

Source is handled by error condition of `cd` and Target is handled by `if not exist`. So if Target does not exist, `exit /b 2`, as it is unsuitable to continue the script. So you can check `errorlevel` 1 or 2 for failure of the script if run i.e. from a command prompt.

Here is a alternative that proceeds to the end of the script:

```
@echo off
set "Source=C:\test"
set "Target=D:\data"

cd "%Source%" 2>nul && (
    if exist "%Target%" (
        for /d %%a in (*) do (
            >  "%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo [test]
            >> "%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo %%a
        )
    )
)

pause
exit
```

Note I changed `||` to `&&` to now condition on success instead of failure.

Goto can help to progress to avoid the parentheses blocks:

```
@echo off
set "Source=C:\test"
set "Target=D:\data"

cd "%Source%" 2>nul || goto :step2

if not exist "%Target%" goto :step2

for /d %%a in (*) do (
    >  "%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo [test]
    >> "%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo %%a
)

:step2

rem other code

pause
exit
```

Comment: In the following example, if D:\data\%%a does not exist, how do I silence the error message :

`@echo off
set Source=C:\test
set Target=D:\data

cd %Source%

for /d %%a in (*) do  (
    >"%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo [test]
    >>"%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo %%a
)
pause
exit`

Comment: It is possible to pause the script instead of exit the script ?

Comment: You could `pause` or even omit the actions based on error condition, though you do need to choose whether the script can continue or not based on either Source or Target or both not existing. This is up to you as being the author of the script.

Comment: `@echo off
    set "Source=C:\test"
    set "Target=D:\data"

    cd "%Source%"

    for /d %%a in (*) do (
        >  "%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo [test]
        >> "%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo %%a
    )
 
 if not exist "%Target%\%%a" exit /b 2
 
 echo done !

    pause
    exit`

Comment: This script exits when the if condition is met. Can we continue the script without having error messages appear ?

Comment: In your last comment code, the `if exist` is after use of `%Target%` which can cause error. Too late do you think to check at that point? My last edit of answer shows how the script can continue. I do not know exactly what you need without the exact details. If you can update the question post with more detail would be great.

Comment: @echo off
set "Source=C:\test"
set "Target=D:\data"

cd %Source%

for /d %%a in (*) do (
if exist "%Target%\%%a" (
    > "%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo [test]
    >> "%Target%\%%a\test.txt" echo %%a
)
)

pause
exit

Comment: It's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following and it should help you understand what is wrong.

```bat
@echo off
setlocal

echo Starting script

echo Checking if directory exists
if exist "C:\test" (
    cd C:\test
    echo ... I found the Directory
    echo.
    echo Running loop
    for /d %%a in (*) do (
        echo.    Processing: "%%a"      
        echo [test]>"%%a\test.txt"
        echo %%a >>"%%a\test.txt"
    )
    echo ...Loop finished
) else (
    echo Whoops the directory "C:\test" does not exist
)
echo.
pause
```